# Re-arranging points on a graph

Tags: r, visualization, igraph, visnetwork

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

nodes_df = structure(list(id = c("Boss", "TeamA", "TeamB", "SubteamA1", 
"SubteamA2", "SubteamA3", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB2", "SubteamB3", 
"employee1", "employee2", "employee3", "employee4", "employee5", 
"employee6", "employee7", "employee8", "employee9", "employee10", 
"employee11", "employee12", "employee13", "employee14", "employee15", 
"employee16", "employee17", "employee18"), label = c("Boss", 
"TeamA", "TeamB", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA3", "SubteamB1", 
"SubteamB2", "SubteamB3", "employee1", "employee2", "employee3", 
"employee4", "employee5", "employee6", "employee7", "employee8", 
"employee9", "employee10", "employee11", "employee12", "employee13", 
"employee14", "employee15", "employee16", "employee17", "employee18"
), group = c("yellow", "red", "red", "green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", 
"purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", 
"purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple", "purple"
)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")

edges_df = structure(list(from = c("Boss", "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", "SubteamA1", 
"SubteamA1", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA2", 
"SubteamA3", "SubteamA3", "SubteamA3", "Boss", "TeamB", "TeamB", 
"TeamB", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB2", 
"SubteamB2", "SubteamB2", "SubteamB3", "SubteamB3", "SubteamB3"
), to = c("TeamA", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA3", "employee1", 
"employee2", "employee3", "employee4", "employee5", "employee6", 
"employee7", "employee8", "employee9", "TeamB", "SubteamB1", 
"SubteamB2", "SubteamB3", "employee10", "employee11", "employee12", 
"employee13", "employee14", "employee15", "employee16", "employee17", 
"employee18")), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")
```

I made the following graph network from this data:

```
 # Create the visNetwork object
    visNetwork(nodes_df, edges_df) %>%   visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "UD") %>%
        visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
        visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
        visInteraction(navigation = "drag")
```

[image]

**My Question:** Is there anything I can do to have this graph network better reflect the "hierarchies" in my data? For example - I would like "boss" to appear at the top, "teams" to appear after, "subteams" to be after and "employees" to be after.

I tried to do this with the  `visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "UD")` option and I can't seem to get this hierarchical order to be reflected in the visualization. Does anyone know what I might be able to do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing nodes in igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873671/fixing-nodes-in-igraph)

Comment: @ Limey: Thank you for your reply! I actually saw this post before posting my question and tried to apply the logic proposed there. However, I was not sure how exactly I can take this line "ly <- layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=which(V(g)$name=='A'),flip.y=T)" and apply it to my visNetwork. Do you have any ideas about this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a column called `level` which has a unique order number for each group, like boss will be number 1 etc. So when having Up to Down layout (`direction = "UD"`) your boss will be top and your last number 4 will be bottom of layout which are the employees. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)

#create level column
nodes_df <- nodes_df %>%
  mutate(level = case_when(group == "yellow" ~ 1,
                           group == "red" ~ 2,
                           group == "green" ~ 3,
                           group == "purple" ~ 4))

# Create the visNetwork object
visNetwork(nodes_df, edges_df) %>%   
  visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "UD") %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "drag")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348270/r-modifying-an-r-markdown-tutorial Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Quinten: Hi Quinten, I have been trying to work on this bountied question for a while - can you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944057/r-shortest-path-calculations

Answer (score 3):

You're overly focussed on `visGraph`.  You don't need it to do what you want to do.

Here is a demonstration, using your definitions of `nodes_df` and `edges_df` above.  The only change from the example I linked to is the change to the label of the root node.

```
library(igraph)

# Create the graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges_df, directed=TRUE, vertices=nodes_df)
# Define the layout
ly <- layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=which(V(g)$name=='Boss'), flip.y=T)
# Plot the graph
plot(g,layout=ly)
```

Giving

[image]