# R: Shortest Path Calculations

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**Based on a geospatial shapefile, I am trying to find out the driving distance between two coordinates.**

First I loaded the shapefile:

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(sfnetworks)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygraph)

# Set the URL for the shapefile
url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/RNF-FRR/files-fichiers/lrnf000r22a_e.zip"

# Create a temporary folder to download and extract the shapefile
temp_dir <- tempdir()
temp_file <- file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.zip")

# Download the shapefile to the temporary folder
download.file(url, temp_file)

# Extract the shapefile from the downloaded zip file
unzip(temp_file, exdir = temp_dir)

# Read the shapefile using the rgdal package
# source: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456748/strategies-for-working-with-large-shapefiles/456798#456798
a = st_read(file.path(temp_dir, "lrnf000r22a_e.shp"), query="select * from lrnf000r22a_e where PRUID_R ='35'")
```

The shapefile looks something like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 570706 features and 21 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5963148 ymin: 665490.8 xmax: 7581671 ymax: 2212179
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert
First 10 features:
   OBJECTID NGD_UID       NAME TYPE  DIR AFL_VAL ATL_VAL AFR_VAL ATR_VAL CSDUID_L                           CSDNAME_L CSDTYPE_L CSDUID_R                           CSDNAME_R CSDTYPE_R PRUID_L PRNAME_L PRUID_R PRNAME_R RANK
1         4 3434819       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3526003                           Fort Erie         T  3526003                           Fort Erie         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
2         5 1358252      South LINE <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU  3551027                Gordon/Barrie Island        MU      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
3         8 1778927       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3512054                           Wollaston        TP  3512054                           Wollaston        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
4        11  731932     Albion   RD <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    2010    2010  3520005                             Toronto         C  3520005                             Toronto         C      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
5        18 3123617  County 41   RD <NA>     640     708     635     709  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T  3511015                     Greater Napanee         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    3
6        20 4814160       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV  3553005     Greater Sudbury / Grand Sudbury        CV      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
7        21 1817031       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3537028                         Amherstburg         T  3537028                         Amherstburg         T      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
8        24 4825761       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO  3554094 Timiskaming, Unorganized, West Part        NO      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
9        25  544891     Dunelm   DR <NA>       1       9       2      10  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY  3526053                      St. Catharines        CY      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
10       28 1835384 Seven Oaks   DR <NA>     730     974     731     975  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP  3515005             Otonabee-South Monaghan        TP      35  Ontario      35  Ontario    5
   CLASS                 _ogr_geometry_
1     23 LINESTRING (7269806 859183,...
2     23 LINESTRING (6921247 1133452...
3     23 LINESTRING (7320857 1089403..
```

Then I tried to calculate the distance by treating the road network as a graph:

```
# Convert the shapefile to an sfnetwork object
net <- as_sfnetwork(a)

# Define the two points of interest in WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.68312))
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.61203, 43.64256))

# Set the CRS of the points to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)
pt1 <- st_sfc(pt1, crs = 4326)
pt2 <- st_sfc(pt2, crs = 4326)

# Transform the points to the CRS of the network
pt1_transformed <- st_transform(pt1, st_crs(net))
pt2_transformed <- st_transform(pt2, st_crs(net))

# Find the nearest points on the network to the transformed points of interest
n1 <- st_nearest_feature(pt1_transformed, net)
n2 <- st_nearest_feature(pt2_transformed, net)
```

Everything seems to work until the last part:

```
# Calculate the shortest path between n1 and n2 on the network
path <- net %>%
    activate(edges) %>%
    mutate(weight = edge_length()) %>%
    as_tbl_graph() %>%
    shortest_paths(n1, n2) %>%
    .$epath[[1]]

# Calculate the distance of the shortest path in meters
distance <- sum(path$weight)

# Print the distance in kilometers
distance_km <- distance / 1000
cat("The network distance between CN Tower and Toronto Airport is", distance_km, "km.")
```

**But this gave me the following error:**

```
Error in .[[.$epath, 1]] : incorrect number of subscripts
In addition: Warning message:
In shortest_paths(., n1, n2) :
  At structural_properties.c:4745 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Note:** I am specifically trying to solve this problem **WITHOUT** using OSRM

Comment: Maybe you can try the `osrm` package? e.g., `osrm::osrmRoute(src = c(-79.61203, 43.68312), dst = c(-79.61203, 43.64256))`

Comment: @ nniloc: thank you for your reply! I already know how to use this function - I am now trying to learn a new way to solve this problem without using OSRM. thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! Did you check what happens after applying the preprocessing steps described in the [second](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/sfn02_preprocess_clean.html) sfnetworks vignette?

Answer (score 0):

try to calculate the shortest path using **dijkstra** from the **igraph** package

```
# Calculate the shortest path between n1 and n2 on the network
net_igraph <- net %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  mutate(weight = edge_length()) %>%
  as_tbl_graph()

path <- igraph::dijkstra(net_igraph, n1, n2, weights = E(net_igraph)$weight)

# Calculate the distance of the shortest path in meters
distance <- path[[2]]

# Print the distance in kilometers
distance_km <- distance / 1000
cat("The network distance between CN Tower and Toronto Airport is", distance_km, "km.")
```