# Visualize all possible syllable combinations

Tags: r, tree, visualization, igraph

I take the 4 syllables " "ha", "mu", "ra", "bi"

Using the following code, I can find out all combinations that can be made with these 4 syllables:

```
library(dplyr)

objects <- c("ha", "mu", "ra", "bi")
combinations <- expand.grid(objects, objects, objects, objects)

combinations$name <- apply(combinations, 1, function(x) {
    paste(x, collapse = "-")
})

combinations$id = 1:nrow(combinations)

combinations <- select(combinations, id, everything())
```

Now, using the igraph package, I am trying to make a network/graph that visualizes all possible combinations of these syllables. This would look something like this:

[image]

Can someone please show me how I can restructure my data to then create this visualization?

Comment: Just FYI, you will likely get much more engagement if you search for some options and try them first - you can then ask  "This is what I've tried and what's working/not working" rather than "Can someone please show me..." which reads as "please do it for me".

Comment: I would start with `make_tree()` setting it to 4 children per vertex and n = the total number of your vertexes - I'm not sure if you'd need +1 for the 'stump' of the tree.  Create that structure and inspect it - from there you should be able to sort and input your data to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with `3` layers

```
objects <- c("ha", "mu", "ra", "bi")

n <- 3 # height of tree
N <- sum(length(objects)^(0:n)) # total number of vertices, including a virtual root

make_tree(N, length(objects)) %>%
  delete.vertices(1) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("name", value = rep(objects, length.out = vcount(.))) %>%
  plot(layout = layout_as_tree)
```

[image]

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: Thank you so much or your answer! I changed n = 4 and it looks great!

Comment: I have been trying to work on this question for a while now but I can't make progress on it - can you please take a look at it if you have time? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944057/r-shortest-path-calculations

Comment: @stats_noob sorry that it is beyond my knowledge and I have no clue about it